# Format/ Style using AlternationIndex

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a itemcontrol and I want to show a button if its mt last item. Is it possible to do this using AlternationIndex?

```
<Button.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundButton}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="0"> <!-- What do I give here? 0 hides first row -->
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Comment: I doubt it is possible this way, because when you add an item, the AlternationIndex of the previous one won't change and hence not update the DataTrigger Binding. So the Button in the now second-last item won't be hidden.

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening on my form and I can't get around this. Thanks for replying anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a little complicated, but you may use a MultiBinding in your DataTrigger, that compares the `AlternationIndex` property to the `Count` property of the ItemsControl's Items:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundButton}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsLastItemConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource
                                              AncestorType=ContentPresenter}"/>
                    <Binding Path="Items.Count"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource
                                              AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The multi-value converter would look like this:

```
public class IsLastItemConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var index = (int)values[0];
        var count = (int)values[1];
        return index == count - 1;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. I get an error Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception. Maybe it can't see IsLastItemConverter?

Comment: You need to add it as resource somewhere, e.g. in your Window's Resources: `<local:IsLastItemConverter x:Key="IsLastItemConverter"/>`.